# Discrete Math - Proving Distributive Laws for Sets by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, induction, proof-explanation

I'm working on doing a proof by induction on this question:

Use induction to prove that if $X_1, . . . , X_n$ and $X$ are sets, then
$X∩(X_1∪X_2∪· · ·∪X_n) = (X∩X_1)∪(X∩X_2)∪· · ·∪(X∩X_n)$.

I've shown the basis case:

$X∩X_1 = X∩X_1$

But I'm having difficulty proving the $n + 1$ case. This is my work so far:

Assume $X∩(X_1∪X_2∪· · ·∪X_n) = (X∩X_1)∪(X∩X_2)∪· · ·∪(X∩X_n)$

Show $X∩(X_1∪X_2∪· · ·∪X_n∪X_{n+1}) = (X∩X_1)∪(X∩X_2)∪· · ·∪(X∩X_n) = (X∩X_1)∪(X∩X_2)∪· · ·∪(X∩X_n)∪(X∩X_{n+1})$

I'm not sure what I'm allowed to do from here. Where can I use the induction hypothesis?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tip show: $X\cap(Y\cup X_{n+1})=(X\cup Y)\cap(X\cup X_{n+1})$ where $Y=X_1\cup\cdots\cup X_n$